# How to get response of Place Autocomplete in the typed language?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, autocomplete, google-places-api

I use Google Place Autocomplete to return place predictions .. when I type in Arabic language , the results shown in Arabic

**The Problem is** after I select , I get the result response in English which is my mobile Language , and when my mobile Language is Arabic I get response in Arabic , it seems to be return the result according to my mobile language .

**For example**

My mobile Language is English ,I typed "القاهرة" ,I selected from suggestions "القاهرة" ,the result is "Cairo" , I want the result to be in Arabic that is the language which I typed

[image]

I tried to set local Language but it doesn't help me ..

**This is my code**

```
PlaceAutocompleteFragment autocompleteFragment = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.place_autocomplete_fragment);
    autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {

            AppSettings.setLang(getApplicationContext(),"ar");

            placeAddress = String.valueOf(place.getAddress());

        }
        @Override
        public void onError(Status status) {

        }
    });
```

And this is the Class that set local language

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import java.util.Locale;

public class AppSettings {
private static final String TAG = "APP_SETTINGS";

public static void setLang(Context context, String lang) {
    lang = lang.equalsIgnoreCase("ar") ? "ar" : "en";
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).edit().putString("txt", lang).apply();
    Configuration newConfig = new Configuration(context.getResources().getConfiguration());
    Locale locale = new Locale(lang);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    newConfig.locale = locale;
    newConfig.setLayoutDirection(locale);
    context.getResources().updateConfiguration(newConfig, null);
}

public static String getLang(Context context) {
    return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).getString("txt", "ar");
}
}
```

**How to make the output in Arabic forever regardless what my mobile language is ?**

Comment: There is a feature request for this in Google issue tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35830937. Please star it to add your vote.